# Is there a LAMP stack all-in-one image available for download?

Tags: development-environment, lamp, virtualbox

Is there a site that has a pre-configured all-in-one LAMP image ready to download and set up for local development, say using VirtualBox or similar?  I want to dabble in some PHP (possibly Django) but for just local testing I'm looking to take the lazy/easy way out and try to find a preconfigured setup that I can download and set up in VirtualBox, similar to how Oracle is/was offering a premade Java environment with Oracle Linux, Netbeans, etc. etc.

Is there such a thing?  Preferably using an IDE of some type like Eclipse?  I **could** download all the things myself but like I said I'm being a bit lazy just for a local development environment to dabble with.  I've looked at `www.turnkeylinux.org` but that's not quite what I want; I don't need an easy way to manage it, I just want a setup I can install that will already have Apache/PHP/MySQL (or Postgres, doesn't matter) and preferably Eclipse already installed, so I can just load it up into VirtualBox and log in to some form of Linux and start to get thing set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [VMWare Virtual Applliance Marketplace](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/). This has a wide variety of virtual machines, preconfigured to specific use cases.

I haven't looked to see if it's got a *specific* solution for you but, if not, you may want to consider uploading any you create to assist others in future.

You could also find one which had *most* of what you need, then simply add what's missing.

Answer (score 4):

BitNami has a number of preconfigured VM images available for download that can be used in VirtualBox or VMWare Player for free

LAMP Stack: http://bitnami.org/stack/lampstack

IDE is not included, but you could share your source code from your OS to the VM and use whatever IDE you want to natively.

Theres also [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) (Win) and [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) (OSX) that install the entire LAMP stack natively, no VM needed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **[Devilbox](https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox)**. It is an os independent docker LAMP/MEAN development stack which is pre-configured out of the box and offers features as such:

- PHP: 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3
- Xdebug
- automated vhost creation
- unlimited number of projects
- valid https for all projects
- email catch-all
- automated DNS
- phpMyAdmin, phpRedmin, Adminer, OpCacheGUI
- Apache, Nginx, MongoDB, MySQL, MariaDB, PerconaDB, PostgreSQL, Redis, Memcached, MailHog, Solr, RabbitMQ, etc
- [Extensive documentation](https://devilbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[image: devilbox]

**Project:**

- Github: https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox
- Documentation: https://devilbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- Gitter: https://gitter.im/devilbox/Lobby
- Website: http://devilbox.org/

> The Devilbox is a modern and highly customisable dockerized PHP stack supporting full LAMP and MEAN and running on all major platforms. The main goal is to easily switch and combine any version required for local development. It supports an unlimited number of projects for which vhosts, SSL certificates and DNS records are created automatically. Email catch-all and popular development tools will be at your service as well. Configuration is not necessary, as everything is already pre-setup.
>
> Furthermore, the Devilbox provides an identical and reproducable development environment for different host operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out vagrantcloud.com and the vagrantup.com site. They have quite a number of useful vms you can bring up and play with to work with some specific piece of technology right off the bat.